# What is the efficient way to generate unique id in mysql with node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, uuid

I am pretty new to node js.I am confused that what is the efficient way and without affecting performance to generate unique id with mysql/nodejs.I don't want last insert id.I want unique id like facebook and google does...

Comment: A search on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/uuid) show some [interesting package](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid).

Comment: use UUID's. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var uuid = require("uuid");
console.log(uuid.v4()); // something like 3cbfe5fd-ce71-47c1-a7d0-af35d6628f64
```